# Alternative key-binding mode in X-Monad

Tags: xmonad

In X-Monad, can I define an alternative set of key bindings for when a
certain window is active?

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindowState :: X (WindowSet)
getWindowState = do
    XState { windowset = old } <- get
    return $ old
```

The above gets you the `WindowSet`, next you're looking for the 'focused' window, once you have that you can do a simple if else and the appropriate action.

Comment: Thank you!  If you want to, I'd appreciate a full example, since I don't
know any Haskell yet; which I wrote but someone for some reason deleted.